# Most basic fantasy combat simulator

Tags: python, beginner, battle-simulation

I was wondering if anyone had anything to recommend for how to clean up the code I made below. Essentially I am asking if my code is messy or not and if there are any recommendations for my improvement.

```
# Most basic fantasy combat simulator
import random

p_health = 5
g_health = 5
goblin_alive = True

def status():
    if g_health == 5:
        return "\nA menacing goblin stands before you..."
    elif g_health >= 3:
        return "\nThe goblin is looking a little tired, and is bleeding..."
    elif g_health >= 1:
        return "\nThe goblin is bleeding horribly and looks enraged..."

while goblin_alive:
    if g_health <= 0:
        goblin_alive = False
        print("\nCongrats you slayed the goblin!")
        again = input("Play again? Y/N: ")

        if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
            goblin_alive = True
        elif again == 'N' or again == 'n':
            print("\nGoodbye")
            exit()
    if p_health <= 0:
        print("Oh dear you have died horribly and the goblin cuts your head off for a trophy...")
        again = input("Play again? Y/N: ")

        if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
            p_health = 5
            g_heath = 5
            goblin_alive = True
        elif again == 'N' or again == 'n':
            print("\nGoodbye")
            exit()

    desc = status()
    print(desc)
    print("You have " + str(p_health) + ' hit points.')

    attack = input("Press enter to attack: ")
    if attack == '':
        print("\nYou swing your sword fiercely at the goblin!")
        hit_type = random.randint(1, 2)
        if hit_type == 1:
            damage = random.randint(1, 3)
            print("You deal a fierce blow for " + str(damage) + " damage to the goblin.")
            g_health = g_health - damage
        elif hit_type == 2:
            damage = random.randint(1, 3)
            print("The goblin slashes you for " + str(damage) + " damage, uh oh...")
            p_health = p_health - damage
    else:
        print("\nYou better do something...")
```

Comment: @close voters, why?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good and was easy to understand, at least for me :)

A few things you can do to improve it:

## Python String Format and Upper

Consider using python [format()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method, instead of:

```
print("You have " + str(p_health) + ' hit points.')
```

try:

```
print('You have {} hit points.'.format(p_health))
```

And when checking if a char equals to a given char, you don't have to check both cases you can just use Python upper/lower function so instead of:

```
if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
```

try:

```
if again.lower() == 'y':
    do stuff
```

---

## Better Practice

The status() function could be improved by assigning a value to result and returning it, this is just better practice:

```
def status():
    res = ''
    if g_health == 5:
        res = "\nA menacing goblin stands before you..."
    elif g_health >= 3:
        res = "\nThe goblin is looking a little tired, and is bleeding..."
    elif g_health >= 1:
        res = "\nThe goblin is bleeding horribly and looks enraged..."
    return res
```

---

## Python Class

Perhaps this code will be better in a GoblinGame class, this class will have properties such as goblin_health, player_health and goblin_alive that can be assigned when initializing the class instance, and a run() method to play a round of the game, I've wrote a quick sample class you can follow along from there:

```
class GoblinGame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player_health = 5
        self.goblin_health = 5

    def goblin_alive(self):
        return self.goblin_health > 0

    @property
    def status(self):
        res = ''
        if self.goblin_health == 5:
            res = "\nA menacing goblin stands before you..."
        elif self.goblin_health >= 3:
            res = "\nThe goblin is looking a little tired, and is bleeding..."
        elif self.goblin_health >= 1:
            res = "\nThe goblin is bleeding horribly and looks enraged..."
        return res

    def run(self):
        while self.goblin_alive:
         # write the game logic...
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I fail to see how the changes improve the `status` function. Can you expand a bit on why you consider it's better?

Comment: I feel like the changes for the status function might help me get in the practice of using variables that are a bit easier to change? I also was wondering about the status function changes.

Answer (score 1):

The code was clear and readable. Good job.

**Bug?**

That said, there appears to be a bug in the "play again" logic:

```
    if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
        goblin_alive = True
    elif again == 'N' or again == 'n':
        print("\nGoodbye")
        exit()
```

It seems like you mark the goblin as alive, but don't give it any health. So the next game the goblin will start out ... dead?

**More Functions!**

I suggest that you write some more functions. There are places in your code where you are "repeating yourself", and this violates the *DRY principle* (don't repeat yourself)!

Specifically, there is this code in the "goblin health" section:

```
    again = input("Play again? Y/N: ")

    if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
        goblin_alive = True
    elif again == 'N' or again == 'n':
        print("\nGoodbye")
        exit()
```

There is similar code (but better) in the "player health" section. I'd suggest that you write a function called `play_again()` that asks the question and evaluates the response and returns either True or False.

Then you can write another function, `reset_game()` that resets the global variables for you (you'll want to use the [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) keyword for this).

You can then write code like:

```
if play_again():
    reset_game()
else:
    exit()
```

**Magic Numbers**

Finally, I encourage you to define a pair of *constants* to use in place of the [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) 1 and 2:

```
# Near the top of the module
PLAYER_HITS = 1
GOBLIN_HITS = 2

    # Later in the code:
    if hit_type == PLAYER_HITS:
        damage = random.randint(1, 3)
        print("You deal a fierce blow for " + str(damage) + " damage to the goblin.")
        g_health = g_health - damage
    elif hit_type == GOBLIN_HITS:
```

Comment: Thank you! The magic numbers is definitely something I should be aware of, I also hadn't noticed the play again bug, and I believe you were correct, the goblin was indeed dead upon playing again. I appreciate the tips! My next goal is to create similar programs to practice the above concepts

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue expanding this game, you should consider moving the actors to classes. So you can have a `Unit` class, which is subclassed by both `Player` and `Goblin`:

First, the `Unit` class. A unit should have health, maximum health, attack and a name. It can attack other things, be attacked, display its status, be dead or alive and die:

```
class Unit:
    def __init__(self, name, health, attack_die):
        self.name = name
        self.max_health = health
        self.health = health
        self.attack_damage = attack_die

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self.health}/{self.max_health} HP, {self.attack_damage[0]}-{self.attack_damage[1]} ATK)"

    @property
    def alive(self):
        return self.health > 0

    def attack(self, other):
        damage = random.randint(*self.attack_damage)
        other.being_attacked(damage)
        return damage

    def being_attacked(self, damage):
        self.health -= damage

    def die(self, from_what=None):
        if from_what is None:
            print(f"\nCongrats you slayed the {self.name}!")
        else:
            print(f"{self.name} was slayed by {from_what}!")
```

Now, the `Goblin` class just adds your flavor texts on top of that as well as setting the values fro health and attack:

```
class Goblin(Unit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Goblin", 5, (1, 3))

    def __str__(self):
        if self.health == self.max_health:
            return "\nA menacing goblin stands before you..."
        elif self.health >= 0.5*self.max_health:
            return "\nThe goblin is looking a little tired, and is bleeding..."
        elif self.health >= 0:
            return "\nThe goblin is bleeding horribly and looks enraged..."

    def attack(self, other):
        damage = super().attack(other)
        print(f"The goblin slashes you for {damage} damage, uh oh...")
```

And finally the `Player` class. It also mostly just adds nice prints:

```
class Player(Unit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Player", 5, (1, 3))

    def __str__(self):
        return f"You have {self.health} hit points."

    def attack(self, other):
        damage = super().attack(other)
        print(f"You deal a fierce blow for {damage} damage to the {other.name}.")

    def die(self, from_what):
        if isinstance(from_what, Unit):
            print(f"\nOh dear you have died horribly and the {from_what.name} cuts your head off for a trophy...")
        else:
            print(from_what)
```

Now most of the complicated stuff is abstracted away and actually running the game becomes quite minimal:

```
def play_round(player, enemy):
    units = [player, enemy]
    while player.alive and enemy.alive:
        print(enemy)
        print(player)
        attack = input("Press enter to attack: ")
        if attack == '':
            random.shuffle(units)
            attacker, defender = units
            print(f"\nYou swing your sword fiercely at the {enemy.name}!")
            attacker.attack(defender)
        else:
            print("\nYou better do something...")
    if player.alive:
        enemy.die()
    else:
        player.die(enemy)


def play_game():
    again = True
    while again:
        play_round(Player(), Goblin())
        again = input("Play again? Y/N: ").lower() == "y"
    print("\nGoodbye")
    exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_game()
```

Comment: Thank you, I found this very helpful as I've considered fidgeting with the code to try and expand it, currently learning a bit about modules, this has been a great exercise to get some practical knowledge on some of the basic concepts i've learned with python so far.